# HTML: Position 3 tables side by side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have 3 tables inside 3 individual `div`s. I want to position them side by side.
The leftmost table has no `thead` field. The middle and the rightmost field has them.

I am using the following HTML and CSS for this(the actual code has a lot of Angular stuff mixed in. I have removed them because they play no part in this):

```css
#marks-table {
 overflow-x: scroll;
 max-width: 600px;
 border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#students-table {
 border-right: none;
}

#students-table td {
 padding-left: 10px;
}

.viewjournal-table td, .viewjournal-table th, .viewjournal-table tr {
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.total-markcolumn-width {
 width: 40px;
}

.viewjournal-table-total td {
 background-color: #eee;
}

.viewjournal-table-total td, .viewjournal-table-total th {
 height: 30px;
 border: 1px solid #ddd;
 border-left: none;
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-7" style="display: flex">

    <div>
        <div id="no-borders">
            <div style="border: none ; display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse"><button ><img src="Left Arrow Button"></button></div>
        </div>
        <table  class="viewjournal-table" id="students-table">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="text-nowrap">
                <td colspan="2">Dummy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div id="marks-table">

        <div class="text-center">Some data</div>

        <div>
            <table class="viewjournal-table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="markcolumn-width text-center">
                        <a href="Some URL">Some Data</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="text-nowrap">
                    <td class="markcolumn-width text-center mark-font" title="Some Data">
                        <span>Some Data</span>
                        <input type="text"size="3"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div>
        <table class="viewjournal-table-total">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left: none;">1</th>
                <th class="text-center">2</th>
                <th class="text-center">г</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="text-nowrap">
                <td class="total-markcolumn-width text-center mark-font" >
                    Some Data</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div><th style="border: none"><button class="table-arrow"><img src="Right arrow button"></button></th></div>
</div>
```

What is get looks something like this: 
[image]

The leftmost and rightmost table's starting positions are wrong. They should start from 1 row below in comparison to the central table.

How do I do it?

**NB: The class "col-md-7" is a Bootstrap class**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div class="col-md-7" style="display: flex">

    <div>
        <div id="no-borders">
            <div style="border: none ; display: flex; flex-direction: row-reverse"><button ><img src="Left Arrow Button"></button></div>
        </div>
        <table  class="viewjournal-table" id="students-table">
            <tbody>
            <tr class="text-nowrap">
                <td colspan="2">Dummy</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="height: 20px"></tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <div id="marks-table">      

        <div> 
        <div class="text-center">Some data</div>
            <table class="viewjournal-table">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th class="markcolumn-width text-center">
                        <a href="Some URL">Some Data</a>
                    </th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr class="text-nowrap">
                    <td class="markcolumn-width text-center mark-font" title="Some Data">
                        <span>Some Data</span>
                        <input type="text"size="3"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div>
    <div>
    <div></div>
        <table class="viewjournal-table-total">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="text-center" style="border-left: none;">1</th>
                <th class="text-center">2</th>
                <th class="text-center">г</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr class="text-nowrap">
                <td class="total-markcolumn-width text-center mark-font" >
                    Some Data</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div><th style="border: none"><button class="table-arrow"><img src="Right arrow button"></button></th></div>
</div>
```

Hi, I think you need to add the same numbers of div before three tables, so that they are aligned. I added two div to the third table, and changed sequence  for the second one. Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

the first div and second div has a div before the the table tag. but the third don't. so the tables are not on the same horizontal grid. you can try to add div tags to align.or move the title tags out. for example, put the three table into one div tag.